# Unix how to copy file to directory and echo

Tags: bash, shell-script, echo, recursive

I am trying to write a script using a for loop to copy files to a directory that will also echo the copy command to the terminal. I have successfully gotten the script to copy files, however, am having issues making it `echo` each copy command to the terminal. For example, if it copies files `a`, `b`, and `c`, to directory `2`, I want it to say each time it copies a file `path/file copied to /path/path/directory`.

This is what I have so far:

```sh
for i in /Users/ashleyschumann/Pictures                          
do
    cp -r ./Pictures ./BACKUP_FILES2

    #echo "filename copied to BACKUP_FILES2"
    #echo "$fn copied to $ashleyschumann/BACKUP_FILES2"
done
```

The two commented lines I have both tried and neither got the desired result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for something different from `cp -v`?

Comment: ... or `rsync -v`

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop only results in *one* item and this is then not used in your cp command. 
It could look like this:

```
BACKUP_DIR="/Users/ashleyschumann/BACKUP_FILES2/"
for item in /Users/ashleyschumann/Pictures/*
do
    cp -r $item ./BACKUP_FILES2
    echo "$item copied to $BACKUP_DIR"
done
```

But as muru already stated `cp -v` will do this.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using this in combination with set -x at the top of my script and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to enable verbose mode on the copy command

```
cp -av Pictures BACKUP_FILES2/
```

Or

```
rsync -av Pictures BACKUP_FILES2/
```

If you want to customise the message you need to iterate across the files. Since you haven't told us whether or not `Pictures` contains directories of files, I'm going to provide some alternative solutions.

First, a single level directory of files

```
#!/bin/bash
# Backup files from a single level directory
target=BACKUP_FILES2/Pictures

# ensure target exists
mkdir -p "$target"

# here we go
for pic in Pictures/*
do
    if [[ -f "$pic" ]]
    then
        # it's a file
        cp -p "$pic" "$target/" &&
            echo "Copied $pic" >&2
    fi
done
```

Next a couple of options for a directory tree of files.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Backup a tree of files using cp and a customised message
target=BACKUP_FILES2

find Pictures -exec bash -c '
    for i in "$@"
    do
        if [[ -d "$i" ]]
        then
            mkdir -p "/tmp/target/$i" && echo "Created directory $i" >&2
        else
            cp -p "$i" /tmp/target/"$i" && echo "Copied $i" >&2
        fi
    done
' _ {} +
```

Or

```
#!/bin/bash
# Backup a tree of files using rsync and a customised message
target=BACKUP_FILES2

find Pictures -type f -exec bash -c '
    for i in "$@"
    do
        rsync -aqR --no-r "$i" "$target" && echo "Copied $i" >&2
    done
' _ {} +
```